# How ActiveSupport knows user TimeZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my Linux server in New York, configured to GMT.

All my dates are being saved in UTC.

To return these dates to client, the only thing I need to do is ?

```
date = my_date.utc_to_local
```

No matters where my client is in the world ?

Do Rails knows where my client is ?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326570/rails-how-to-get-the-current-users-time-zone-when-using-heroku

Comment: It looks more complicated than I thought... I will consider using browser-timezone-rails gem.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Rails will always store the date/times in UTC. If you don't like that, you can change it like this:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
end
```

No matter how the date/times are stored in the database it will always convert it to the application default timezone:

For example:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end
```

I hope that helps! Let me know if you want more details!

Comment: Hi Tom, I´ve got this to work, partially, last week. I have some problems with TIME fields that I use to store only hours. I was seriously thinking to change all my TIME columns to DATETIME.