# Possible to get the current timezone from JSON API request (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, http, time

I've got a Rails JSON API that gets called by my client app, ie:

```
[GET] /posts?time=today
```

Previously I was getting today's date by calling `Date.today`, but this causes bugs because it uses the server's timezone and not the user's timezone.

I know it's a long shot, but is there a way to fix this without having to update the client to pass in the current timezone? I could do an IP lookup, but it seems too heavyweight. Is the timezone information passed in anywhere in the request?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12326703/3399504

Comment: @ErvalhouS This is not a duplicate. The linked question is about getting the user's timezone from their browser. This question is about a JSON API.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is also covered in one of the answers of that question.